# Excluding deeply nested dependency in maven for sbt

Tags: maven, sbt

I have a project with the following dependency tree.

```
my:project:jar:1.0
+- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.0:compile
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.4:compile
|  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.0-FCS:compile
|  |  |  +- maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:1.3:plugin
```

maven-cobuertura-pluging provides a `pom` and a `jar`, but jaxen declares a dependency on of type `plugin`.  It appears that this is acceptable to maven, but a later part of our build uses sbt as its build tool.  Sbt complains that it is unable to resolve the dependency:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
:: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
maven-plugins#maven-cobertura-plugin;1.3!maven-cobertura-plugin.plugin
```

I attempted to exclude the dependency in the top level pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <!-- Exclude dependencies that are not needed for building and are misconfigured, causing errors in sbt -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>maven-cobertua-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If I run `mvn dependency:tree`, cobertura is no longer listed.  However, `sbt` still finds the dependency and complains about it.

I deleted ~/.ivy/cache/my/project, so any cached references to the old pom should be gone.

I also tried running `sbt update`, but it failed to execute because of the missing dependency.

Should `sbt` be observing the maven exclusion?  Or do I need to set up an exclusion in `build.sbt` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to sbt 0.13.11 could help.
See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2109